# How to embed FileChooser into application with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I'm trying to figure out how I can use JavaFX to make a FileChooser panel that is directly embedded into the application. Essentially, the FileChooser should always be open since the application relies on the FileChooser, so I'm looking to have the FileChooser directly inside the window where the rest of the GUI is, so it won't have to be opened in a separate window.

Is this possible, or would the entire FileChooser have to be manually coded?

Comment: It would have to be manually coded. The JavaFX `FileChooser` is simply a hook into the native OS file chooser: there is no way to embed that into a Java/JavaFX application.